# Sort records from different tables

Tags: php, sql, sorting, join

I have two table with an column 'minute'.
These table are joined with a INNER JOIN.
Now I want to print out all the records from both tables sorted on both the columns 'minute'

Example

Table 1: name - minute

```
 John - 1
 Marc - 3
```

Table 2: name - minute

```
Gareth - 2
Joe - 3
```

Output:

```
John, Gareth, Marc, Joe
```

The two tables have to remain two separate tables.

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069784/order-by-in-inner-join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use UNION :-

```
 (SELECT  *
 FROM    table1)
    UNION 
 (SELECT  *
 FROM    table2)

 ORDER BY minute ASC
```

Output:-

```
john    1
gareth  2
marc    3
joe     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT name
FROM
(
  SELECT name, [minute],1 AS sort FROM Table1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT name, [minute],2 AS sort FROM Table2
) T
ORDER BY [minute],sort
```

output

```
name    minute
John    1
Gareth  2
Marc    3
Joe     3
```

OR

```
SELECT name, [minute]
FROM
(
  SELECT name, [minute] FROM Table1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT name, [minute] FROM Table2
) T
ORDER BY [minute]
```

output

```
name    minute
John    1
Gareth  2
Joe     3
Marc    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select name
From table1
Union all
Select name
From table2
order by minute
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT name, minute FROM table1, table2 ORDER BY table1.minute,table2.minute ASC;
```

Comment: didn't think if you used a join you would be able to get two name fields if they are both called join